# Floating point exception with MPI_ALLREDUCE

Tags: fortran, mpi, gfortran, openmpi

I am using gfortran v.9.3.0 and openmpi v.4.1.0.
When I compile my application in debug mode with specifically this flag that checks for floating exception.

`-ffpe-trap=invalid,zero,overflow,underflow`,

I get floating point exception when invoking the routine:

```
use mpi
integer::n
double precision ::phi(n)

call MPI_AllReduce(MPI_IN_PLACE,phi,n,MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION,MPI_SUM,MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)
```

I check the minimum and maximum values of `phi` and both of these figures are within reasonable range.

The only thing I see is different ranks might have reverse numbers so the sum will be zero or close to zero. But would that really trigger a floating exception:

The error:

```
[server-0:3718 :0:3718] Caught signal 8 (Floating point exception: floating-point underflow)
[server-0:3720 :0:3720] Caught signal 8 (Floating point exception: floating-point underflow)
[-server-0:3721 :0:3721] Caught signal 8 (Floating point exception: floating-point underflow)
==== backtrace (tid:   3718) ====
 0 0x0000000000055365 ucs_debug_print_backtrace()  /software/contrib/../src/ucs/debug/debug.c:656
 1 0x00000000000c7fa5 ompi_op_base_2buff_sum_fortran_double_precision()  op_base_functions.c:0
 2 0x00000000000a9ada ompi_coll_base_allreduce_intra_recursivedoubling()  ???:0
 3 0x00000000000056c5 ompi_coll_tuned_allreduce_intra_dec_fixed()  ???:0
 4 0x0000000000064fb9 MPI_Allreduce()  ???:0
 5 0x0000000000046739 ompi_allreduce_f()  ???:0
 6 0x000000000061f881 __parallel_MOD_global_sum_dble_vector()  mpifuncs.f90:490
 7 0x0000000000f168ee sol_()  tt1.f90:244
 8 0x000000000102a033 MAIN__()  tt.f90:66
 9 0x000000000102a449 main() tt.f90:24
10 0x0000000000022555 __libc_start_main()  ???:0
11 0x0000000000409c63 _start()  ???:0
```

Comment: It's trapping on underflow. Are you sure you want to do this/know what this means? Beyond that without a complete program it is all but impossible to say more.

Comment: I got some problems on other parts of the code where I believe it does some illegal operations, and the unfortunate thing is that it is trapped somewhere before that part I am looking after. I am not sure what it exactly means, I just put all the flags related to the exception errors

Comment: The above is trapping on floating point underflow - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_underflow . In most scientific codes this is not a problem at all, though I can't be certain about yours as you give no details. I would just omit trapping on underflow (but keep the rest of the traps) and then see what happens.

Comment: Thanks @IanBush. Unfortunately, it does not seem to do good. My problem is when using gfortran+openmpi with more than 1 rank I get troubles with my numerics. Using ifort+openmpi no problems whatsoever. Hence, I tried to be aggressive with my debug flags to see if anything flags up, but no luck. It is really tricky